# Entity framework recursively populate children of DTO

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

So I have a DataTable object, which I want to populate based on a table from my database. Currently, I do the following:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<DataDTO>> Loadreferences(int Id)
{
    IEnumerable <DataDTO> DTOList = _context.Data.Where(p => p.Id == Id).Select(p => new DataDTO
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        Children = p.Children
    });
    return Task.FromResult(DTOList);
}
```

The original table in my database is called Data and contains a lot of other stuff that I have left out for this question. However, the point in constructing this datatable object is basically to reduce the payload towards the server (as it leaves out some of the columns and transform others)

I can successfully populate my DTO, but I have a problem populating the children. Naturally this is because, the list of children is pointing to objects of type `Data`, and I try to use it in type `DataDTO`.

Therefore, I get an error stating that I can't convert a list of `Data` objects to a list of `DataDTO` objects.

Do I really need a loop to fix this for me, or can I do it with a simple query?

Comment: Did you `Include` the `Children` during a load from DB? Like it's explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Comment: yes i did :-) The children are nested in the same table - so they are all included

Comment: Use AutoMapper.

Comment: Would prefer not to use 3rd party libraries.

Comment: It looks to me that you haven't included *Children*. Try with *_context.Data.Where(p => p.Id == Id).Include(d => d.Children).Select...*

Comment: I have already tried that, makes no difference when its a mapping inside the same table :-)

Comment: If you don't want to use Automapper, maybe you can try defining a constructor for the DataDTO class that would take a Data type parameter and do your mappings that way. Or maybe define an extension method.

Comment: Can you provide the exact, verbatim exception that you are receiving ? May help others get a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: Also, you're iterating over an `Enumerable` of type `Data` and filtering for a matching `Id`. Then trying to create a DTO object. The part I'm confused on is you're saying that type `Data` has a property `Children` that is an `IEnumerable` of type `Data` ? The types aren't making sense here. Could you please clarify or provide the code for your class definitions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out, that there was a relatively easy fix to this:

```
foreach (DataDTO data in datas)
{
    data.Children = datas.Where(p => p.ParentId == data.Id).ToList();
}
```

By doing the following, I didn't have to recursively add new objects in my select statement or do some sort of stored procedure.

The loop simply checks if any items in the list has the current looped item as `parentId`, whereafter it appends to the children property.